# Can access shares by IP, not Name, but not a DNS issue

Tags: shared-folders

My users can access a shared folder by `\\10.10.10.10\folder` but :

- When they use `\\FS\folder` it correctly resolves to `10.10.10.10`, but they don't get logged in.
  In addition they are asked to authenticate on `DOMAIN1`
  while `10.10.10.10` is actually on `DOMAIN2`,
  so they are asked to enter username/password for the wrong domain.
- With `\\10.10.10.10\folder`, they are NOT asked to authenticate.

I have watched the login on Wireshark and can see that `FS` gets resolved
correctly, and they do get prompted for a username and password.

Why do they only get prompted for the username/password when they log in by server name and not by IP address?

Comment: BTW... I typed this in as a double slash before FS and 10.10.10.10, but only 1 slash showed up in the output text.

Comment: I heavily edited your post for clarity, please verify that I didn't make a mistake.